# whmcs cron not running says ioncube not installed

Tags: cron, ioncube

ioncube is installed on my server, this can be verified at http://www.webhostingmumbai.co.in/phpinfo.php

but when i run the cron at webhostingmumbai.co.in/manage/crons/cron.php , it gives me the following error:

Site error: the file **/nfs/c04/h03/mnt/60142/domains/webhostingmumbai.co.in/html/manage/crons/cron.php** requires the ionCube PHP Loader ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so to be installed by the website operator. If you are the website operator please use the [ionCube Loader Wizard](http://www.ioncube.com/lw/) to assist with installation.

in php.ini the ioncube installation has been mentioned at webhostingmumbai.co.in/ioncube/...

can someone help me what what needs to be done to make the cron work?

Answer (score 0):

The php.ini file at /nfs/c04/h03/mnt/60142/etc/php.ini is the one being used by default. The server uses CGI, so a php.ini file found in the same location as the first page of a request may take precedence. See if you have php.ini files anywhere within your hosting area and ensure that the Loader is reference in each one just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try to run following command via SSH to check which php.ini files are loaded on your server

```
php -i | grep -i 'php.ini'
```

and be sure that you add ioncube zend_extension path to all files which you get listed by this command.

Also check whether full path to whmcs installation directory is set or not in cron config.php

goto 
whmcsfolder/crons/

you will see config.php file , add the complete path to whmcs installation directory like

```
$whmcspath = '/var/www/html/clientarea/';
```

where clientarea is whmcs root directory.
This will definitely help you.